# Узнать, содержит ли строка1 (в БД) строку 2

Tags: запрос, php, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица `table` в БД. В ней есть поле `box`. В поле лежит строка такого вида:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 25
```

##### Задача

Выбрать все строки, где в поле `box` содержится число `2`.

##### Почему не подходит

###### `LIKE`

Потому что он найдет не только число `2`, но и `25`. Нужно найти именно число 2.

###### `explode()`

Потому что тогда придется вынимать сразу все строки и уже проходить по ним циклом. А строк будет много.

**Нужно обойтись только sql-запросом. Буду очень благодарна, если кто-нибудь подскажет, в каком направлении двигаться!**

Comment: В сторону [нормализации данных](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B4).

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб найти слово, можно использовать регулярные выражения `REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'`.
Так:

```
SELECT 
  '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 25' REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]' AS yes1, 
  '1, 3, 4, 5, 25, 2' REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]' AS yes2,
  '2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 25' REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]' AS yes3,
  '1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 25' REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]' AS no1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE table='2'
```

2 - это число, которое должно быть в строке table, то есть если будут заяптые, то не считается. А лучше выводить по id строки. То есть у вас в таблице

```
id | table 
1      2

WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: Ничего не поняла.
Во-первых, `table` - не строка, а таблица.
Во-вторых, я уже описала, что в поле `box` лежит **строка с числами**, а не число.
А то, что Вы написали, не только к теме не относится, но еще и описывает элементарные вещи, которые знает каждый.

Answer (score 0):

а почему не подходит LIKE %2**,**%

запятая не даст выбрать 25

Comment: @myvzar, потому что `27, 102, 15` подойдет.

Comment: Потому что двойка может быть где угодно. Может быть в начале, в середине, в конце. В последнем случае запятой не должно быть после двойки.

Comment: а 2 запятые? LIKE %, 2,%

Comment: @myvzar Тогда не подойдет `2`

---

я даже сразу скажу, что решение этой задачи - это три LIKE через OR, только все равно буду упирать на то, что там не лайки плодить надо, а данные нормализовать и жить, словно заплативши налоги.

Comment: Etki, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Прочитай от корочки до корочки, по времени займет не более 5 минут. Поймешь все о SELECT и не будешь больше задавать таких глупых вопросов.
http://www.site-do.ru/db/sql4.php

Для таблицы потребуется всего строчка

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE box=2;

SELECT * FROM Название таблицы WHERE Название поля где есть число 2=2; и все

Comment: Мда, и правильнее называть не поле, а колонка, чтобы людей в заблуждение не кидать. Строка и поле.

Comment: @xTIGRx, там ненормализованные данные, там валяются строки типа

    id   | box
    1    | '1, 2, 15'
    2    | '123, 2, 1'

не будет там никакого `WHERE box = 2`

Comment: Etki правильно написал. Там хранится **строка** вида:

    1, 7, 4, 9, 14, 2

, а не двойка.